# Flip characters in java

Tags: java

so by the title, I am trying to flip characters from one value, to the opposite value. For example, - would become +, and + would become minus. These are the only 2 values right now, but I was wondering how I should go about this. So far I have this

```
public static String flip(String s, int index) {
    System.out.print("suuuh");
    String k = s;
    ArrayList<Character> array = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Character c : k.toCharArray()) {
        array.add(c);
        System.out.print(c);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i > index; i++) {
        if (array.get(i) == '-') {

            array.set(i, '+');
        } else {
            array.set(i, '+');
        }

    }
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (Character c : array) {
        builder.append(c.toString());
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

but it does not flip the + to a - or vice versa.

Comment: There is no inherent meaning of "opposite" for the text characters "+", "-" or "A", "B" or "C".  SUGGESTION: create a table of "opposites" (e.g. with a character array).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: If you read it, I stated that "these are th only 2 values right now."

Comment: Why build a `ArrayList<Character>` from the `char[]` returned by `toCharArray()`? Just update the `char[]`, then construct a new string from it using `new String(char[])`.

Comment: After the `else` the line should be `array.set(i, '-');`.  Otherwise, both `.set()` methods change to `+`.

Comment: @Smutje why is that a duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic approach is correct, although I would recommend a `HashMap` to store the opposites.

The reason your code does nothing is because

```
for (int i = 0; i > index; i++) {
```

should be something else, probably

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
```

At the moment, the loop is terminating immediately.

Also, the `else` should be

```
array.set(i, '-');
```

Another improvement is that there is no point using a `List<Character>` for this; you can use the `char` returned by `toCharArray()` directly.

Comment: Good catch. And the `else` should be `array.set(i, '-');`, as noted by @SciProg in a comment.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks. Do you know what `index` is for? I don't want to correct this code incorrectly.

Comment: And since you recommend improvements, I'd recommend using the `char[]` returned by `toCharArray()` directly, instead of boxing all the characters into a `List<Character>`.

Comment: Paul, no I don't. The `print("suuuh")` is also a bit weird. ;-)

Comment: @KobeyRafferty Glad we could help!